# Luis 409 on Training model

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I encounter the **409 - conflict** error when I try to "Train" the luis model. When I click on train, the system remains stationary with the following message:

> Training app ... (4/37) completed

From the web console I read that the error encountered is **409**.

Thanks everyone for the support.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the error? In which region is your model published?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by Microsoft, it was their configuration problem.